# Siebel DB question

Tags: c#, siebel

One of my client has a Siebel program installed and a .DBF database. I'd like to know if it's possible to make requests directly to this "db file" within a c# application? 
Do I need to install Siebel on my dev machine too?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It worked. You'll need some dll and a EXE file :
•   dbctrs8.dll
•   dbcon8.dll
•   dbserv8.dll
•   dbodbc8.dll
•   dblgen8.dll
•   dbeng8.exe

(this is from Siebel 7, but  you'll be able to find what dll you'll need because you'll get an error anyway).

You'll need a computer that has Siebel installed and "copy" the ODBC connection parameters from it. So, go to that computer and go to run, execute, odbcad32. Find the ODBC connection, check the parameters (you'll see the main dll + other parameters). Then go to the target computer and add an ODBC connection with the same parameters.

If the "ODBC Driver" is not available, you'll need to install it manually. I followed the procedure there :
http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3712461/Installing-a-Custom-ODBC-Driver-on-Windows-for-SQL-Anywhere.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dbf is an instance of a local SQL Anywhere database, so you could connect to it via the Siebel Local database driver - or install Siebel Dedicated Web Client and grab the controls that will appear in your C# IDE.